# Cosa significa "soggezione" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Nel racconto *Tempesta solare* di Italo Calvino ho letto (il corsivo è mio):

> Io guardavo Rah nella notte: l'acconciatura fastosa, i gioielli, l'abito cangiante. -- Ti
>   sei messa di gala, -- dissi. 
>         -- Devo ben festeggiare il tuo ritrovamento -- rispose. 
>         Per me non c'era niente da festeggiare; ero ricaduto in un'antica *soggezione*; il mio
>   paziente progetto era fallito. -- Sei sempre più bella -- ammisi.

Ho cercato il vocabolo "soggezione" in alcuni dizionari, ma non riesco a capire del tutto bene quale sia il suo significato in questo contesto. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Essere in soggezione" ha un significato simile ad "avere un timore reverenziale" , una specie di paura causata da qualcosa di, per esempio, estremamente bello o potente.

In questo caso sta ad indicare come qualsiasi schema preparato dalla voce narrante si fosse sciolto di fronto alla bellezza di Rah: ***ne era stregato***.

Un po' come l'equivalente inglese di "to be under someone's spell/charm"